# Horizontal nav bar, search input not aligned

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a horizontal navbar with an input type called "search".

It works well but it's not aligned correctly with the others, using only CSS, not Bootstrap.

Here's what I have so far: https://codepen.io/mugas/pen/gvVwJj

```css
.nav{
 width: 100%;
 float: left;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0 0 3em 0;
 padding: 0;
 text-align: center;
 align-content: right;
}



.nav a{
 display: block;
 padding: 18px 10px;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #020303;
 font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
 float: left;
 list-style: none;
}

.nav a:hover {
 color:#BF250D;
}

#home {
 color:#DE940B; 
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="nav">
    <ul class="container">
    <input type"search" placeholder="Search this Site">
    <a id="home" href="#" !important >Home</a>
    <a href="#">Recipes</a>
    <a href="#">Our Products</a>
    <a href="#">Portugal</a>
    <a href="#">Blog</a>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things,

Your search input is missing an equals, and should be `input type="search"`

You should clear the floats (added `ul:after` css declaration)

Here's solution 1, which makes the search the same size as the nav items by use of padding and is floated to the right. I'd use this one for consistency:

https://codepen.io/xhynk/pen/PQMbwx

Here's solution 2 with margins instead.

https://codepen.io/xhynk/pen/BYXQjb

You could also look at other vertical centering options: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Answer (score 1):

Just add a margin to input like what you did for `a`'s:

```css
.nav {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 3em 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  align-content: right;
}

.nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 18px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #020303;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav input {
  margin: 18px 10px;
}

.nav a:hover {
  color: #BF250D;
}

#home {
  color: #DE940B;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="nav">
    <ul class="container">
      <input type="search" placeholder="Search this Site">
      <a id="home" href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="#">Recipes</a>
      <a href="#">Our Products</a>
      <a href="#">Portugal</a>
      <a href="#">Blog</a>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using `flexbox` or `flex`

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

HTML

Notice i have moved the search outside of the `ul` block.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Good Stuff-If it's good its here</title>

  <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon-32x32.png" type="image/x-icon"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/home.css">
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<nav>
<div class="nav">
  <ul class="container">

  <a id="home" href="#" !important >Home</a>
  <a href="#">Recipes</a>
  <a href="#">Our Products</a>
  <a href="#">Portugal</a>
  <a href="#">Blog</a>
  <a href="#">Ingredients</a>
  <a href="#">Good Stuff</a>  
  </ul>
  <input type"search" placeholder="Search this Site">
</div>
</nav>  


</body>
</html>
```

For the css, I have changed `display` to `flex` and set the parameters as

`justify-content: space-between;` this means it will send the `ul` to the left as it is first and the `search` to the right and leave the space in between empty.

the       `align_items: center;` and `align-content; center` means it will align nicely and simply adding `flex:1` to the `a` tags tells it to apply the attributes..

```
.nav{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex; # Change to flex
  margin: 0 0 3em 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  align-content: right;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align_items: center;
  align-content; center 

}


.nav a{
  flex: 1;
  padding: 18px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #020303;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
  list-style: none;



}

.nav a:hover {
  color:#BF250D;
}

#home {
  color:#DE940B; 
}
```

CODEPEN is here:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VQomMB